# IE9-10 height: 100% doesn't work

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

When I place an absolute positioned div (#window) inside a table-cell div (#cell-2), #window does not display in IE9 and 10. It works fine in other browsers though. I have placed a fiddle at the end of this post demonstrating this.

Here's the html:

```
<body>
    <div id="table">
        <div id="cell-1"></div>
        <div id="cell-2">
            <div id="window"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

#table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}

#cell-1{
    display:table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 210px;
    background-color:black;
}

#cell-2{
    display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
}

#window{
    position:absolute;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[You can find the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7hs0nqvp/12/). You will notice that the right section of the screen correctly displays the yellow div in non-IE browsers. But displays the green div when using IE9 and IE10.

**It is worth noting that #window is a modal window that will be generated dynamically and should cover the contents of #cell-2 that is not necessarily empty. The overflow is required.**

The issue seems to be related to the fact IE seems to ignore height:100%; because height:100px; for example will display as expected.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is the kind of reason I tell people IE is fundamentally broken (that and the security risk inherent in such sloppy code), and I haven't loaded it up except for the 5 seconds it takes to install Firefox in at least 10 years.  I actually get a slight moment of panic any time it accidentally launches in an attempt to handle some file extension from the OS.  I understand most developers don't get to say "I am not going to develop for IE anymore".  I think this is a problem for them and their companies - it is a huge liability and shows a lack of respect for your customers to support IE.

Answer (score 2):

Remove position:absolute from #window class and try, it works!!

```css
#window{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, remove `position:relative` from `#cell-2` and put `position:relative` into the `#window`. The problem really is that position:relative in #cell-2 erases width and height in IE for reasons unknown.

Comment: The catch here is that we want `#window` to behave like a modal. doesn't removing position absolute create potential stacking issues?

@AlexPakka Thanks that explains the issue we're having. At least I understand what it is now.

Comment: I'm going to add to my previous comment, and edit the first post: `#cell-2` might **not** be empty. Thus position absolute guaranteed that `#window` would stack above (z) the content. Both solutions here cause trouble in that case

Answer (score 0):

Try setting padding to 0 and height: auto; in #window.

```
#window{
position:absolute;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
background-color:yellow;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:auto;
padding:0;  <-----
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doesn't seem to work though

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, which version of IE are you using? With what document mode?